# Scene2d setScale(float) on actor/group does not change width or height or coordinates

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Scene2d's **setScale(float)** method does scale the actor and all of it's children appropriately but is not updating the width / height or the x / y properties, causing everything to be out of position. Is this intended and if it is, is there a good work around? Setting the size manually after scaling resizes the children too, making everything too small / big.

Of course it might be possible I am not understanding how it works but I am stuck on this for a while now and can't seem to find a solution.

**Edit: Turns out it works as intented. Here is a screenshot of my problem**

[image]

- Green: actual element
- Orange: original width/height,
- Silver: scaled width/height,
- Silver dot: x and y of the element
- Blue dot: origin, manually set after setting x and y to wished position

This is the outcome after scaling, removing it from one group and adding it to another, then moving the element to its position. **The silver rectangular is where the green element should be**. I get the wished results when the element is unscaled / in original size.

As you can see, the actor / group scaled perfectly and the visual / drawn result is also the one expected. However, the actual element is offset, messing everything up

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is intended. What do you mean by workaround? What problem are you trying to solve? If you want to get visual width for example, just multiply real width with scaleX.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did after I did not find any other solution. First of all thank you for your time, I edited my post to make my problem clear

Comment: "This is the outcome after scaling, removing it from one group and adding it to another, then moving the element to its position." Sorry, hard to understand. "Another" group is the orange/silver one? It would be helpful to look at the code.

Comment: thank you very much, but I found a working solution. What I meant was, I removed the actor from it's container group after scaling and added it to another group. I fixed it by scaling up and down after adding it to the new group

Comment: I didn't really make any contribution to this, but I'm glad it worked out.